# How to insert a line break before specific word in TextView in Android, if line count is more than one?

Tags: android, textview

For example, I have a string «One two three four five» to be set in TextView.

If the text occupies only one line, there’s no change, and it’s OK

If text occupies two lines, then:

- expected result is: «One two \n three four five» (**exactly** after
  "two")
- actual result is: «One two three four \n five» (the line break
  can be anywhere)

Also I have a blank TextView in ConstraintLayout with zero width, so I don’t know the width of the textView before I set text.

How can I achieve this?

As far as I know, the width of text can be measured before setting text and divided by the textView's width, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me, as I don't know the width of textview.

Here's my code:

```
override fun setText(textView: TextView, prefix: String, postfix: String) {
    var fullText = "$prefix $postfix"
    val lines = getLinesCount(textView, fullText)
    if (lines > 1) {
        fullText = fullText.replace(postfix, "\n$postfix")
    }

    textView.text = fullText
}

private fun getLinesCount(textView: TextView, text: String): Int {
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.textSize = textView.textSize
    val rect = Rect()
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, rect)
    // I'm not sure how to calculate textView actual width
    return (ceil(rect.width().toFloat() / textView.width)).toInt() 
}
```

Comment: What have you achieved till now. Can you please add that code?

Comment: how will you know line count?

Comment: updated description

Answer (score 0):

TextView Supports `getLineCount();` which return line count after textview is drawn on UI.

```
int lineCount = textView.getLineCount();
if(lineCount > 2) {
    //your line break logic goes here.
} else {
    //normal logic
}
```

See this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getLineCount%28%29).

You need to use `Html.fromHtml()` to format XML textview in html format.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("One two <br> three four five", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("One two <br> three four five"));
}
```

You can also refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: my problem is to determine whether I have to put the line break, i.e. the text takes two lines

Comment: see my edited answer. If you have any doubt comment here